# session expiring after refreshing page PHP

Tags: php, session

I am having problems with a custom start session.For security reasons I decide to look for a method that is safe when starting a session and I came across this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) and implemented the method related to start session.

The problem is that whenever I am initiating a new session variable and redirect to another page which is expecting the value from the initialized session, all my session variable that I initialed earlier on get  destroyed forcing the user to logout.Below is my function I am using to start sessions:

```
 function sec_session_start(){
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';//set a custom session Name
$secure = false;//true if are using https
$httponly = true; //this stops javascript from accessing session id 

ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);//FORCES session to only use cookies
$cookie_params  = session_get_cookie_params();//Get current cookie params
session_set_cookie_params($cookie_params['lifetime'],$cookie_params['path'],$cookie_params['domain']
        ,$secure,$httponly);
session_name($session_name);//set the session name to the one set above
if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}//start the php session
session_regenerate_id();//regenerate new session id and delete the old one THIS IS TO  PREVENT SESSION HIJACK

}
```

I have searched for an answer to my problem  with no luck, Please help me on this.

N.B - when I use the default session_start
  everything works perfect.

Comment: you should always start the session `session_start()` (and it should be before any output), not when there is no session.

Comment: I  added  `sec_session_start` function on one page,and calling this page on every page

Answer (score 0):

You should start session, not when `$_SESSION` is not set.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}//start the php session
session_regenerate_id();//regenerate new session id and delete the old one THIS IS TO  PREVENT SESSION HIJACK
```

should be

```
session_start();//Start new or resume existing session
session_regenerate_id();//regenerate new session id and delete the old one THIS IS TO  PREVENT SESSION HIJACK
```

Reference: [session_regenerate_id](https://www.php.net/session_regenerate_id)

Comment: I made necessary changes but  still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to put session_start() at top of your php code, as first instruction.